# Deploy MVC application that uses ACS on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am new to Azure Software Development. I have developed a MVC web application. Also I use a simple database implemented via CRUD operations. I have deployed my MVC on the Azure cloud using my login. I have also migrated my database to the Azure Cloud. I followed the below link:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database

I also had to implement an authentication that uses ACS. Accepts google and yahoo credentials. I could do it successfully following the below post:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg429779.aspx

But the ACS is implemented on the localhost. I mean things work well on emulator, but I am not able to publish the web application that uses ACS on the Azure environment.

I tried changing all the localhost references I created by changing to my actual web application name that is hosted on cloud, but no luck.

Please help me how to deploy an MVC application that uses ACS to be hosted on the Azure cloud environment.

Any links will also help or any information. Thanks a lot in advance. I am struck on this for 4 hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do 2 things:

- In ACS, make sure the relying party application uses your public URL (your cloudapp.net address or custom DNS).
- In your web.config, replace all references from localhost your your public URL (you can also automate this [as described here](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/a-few-tips-to-get-up-and-running-with-the-azure-appfabric-access-control-service)).

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. I am going through the link. I will comment again, soon after I complete it. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it...